# Silverlight/C# simple ListView with DataBindings Example

Tags: c#, silverlight, listview, windows-8.1

I'm trying create a simple ListView that is populated by a Dataset/ItemSource.

The goal being that when someone selects ITEM-A I know that the value for that entry is
(ITEM-A has value of 27012)

So have the xaml of (VoidPanel.xaml)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding names.FirstName}" x:Name="lvReasons" IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single">
</ListView>
```

The cs of (VoidPanel.xaml.cs)

```
namespace App01.Win8.Controls
{

    public sealed partial class VoidPanel : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<VoidListElement> names = new ObservableCollection<VoidListElement>();
        public VoidPanel()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            names = new ObservableCollection<VoidListElement>();

            names.Add(new VoidListElement("ITEM-A", "27017"));
            names.Add(new VoidListElement("ITEM-B", "27018"));

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

The Element of class

```
namespace App01.Win8.DataModel
{
    public class VoidListElement
    {
        public VoidListElement(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.LastName = lastname;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is it just doesn't work. I get no items rendered on screen.

I understand that the ListView can define a DataContext, in this case I'm not setting one, so I presume it uses the current class.

I understand that the ListView can define a ItemSource that I have bound to the names.Firstname that should be pulled from the DataContext.

Can someone please give me some tips, or a decent working example.

Comment: What did you edit Soner? I can't see any change to my question. :-)

Comment: Reformatted your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvReasons" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding names}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
     IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single" >
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<VoidListElement> names = new ObservableCollection<VoidListElement>();
```

Comment: Nope. My list is still empty. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER...

So have the xaml of (VoidPanel.xaml)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding names.FirstName}" x:Name="lvReasons" 
**DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"**
IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single">
</ListView>
```

The cs of (VoidPanel.xaml.cs)

```
namespace App01.Win8.Controls
{

    public sealed partial class VoidPanel : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<VoidListElement> names;

    **public ObservableCollection<VoidListElement> names
    { set; get; }**

        public VoidPanel()
        {
            **names = new ObservableCollection<VoidListElement>();**

            names.Add(new VoidListElement("ITEM-A", "27017"));
            names.Add(new VoidListElement("ITEM-B", "27018"));

            this.DataContext = this;
            **this.InitializeComponent();**
        }
    }
}
```

The Element of class

```
namespace App01.Win8.DataModel
{
    public class VoidListElement
    {
        public VoidListElement(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.LastName = lastname;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```